# How do you add a Scrollbar to a MenuAnchor menu in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

In my Flutter application, I have a button that opens a menu, allowing the user to select one of the options from the menu. Since the user will be able to add options to this menu, I imposed a maximum height on my menu such that it can scroll to accommodate all of the options while using a reasonable amount of screen real estate. The menu scrolls as expected, however there is no scrollbar within the menu to indicate to the user that they can scroll through this list. Here is the code and an accompanying video of the scrolling:

```
Row(
  children: [
    Container(
      width: widget.rowWidth / 2,
      child: const Text("Row Title")
    ),
    SizedBox(
      width: widget.rowWidth / 2,
      child: MenuAnchor(
        style: MenuStyle(
          maximumSize: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith((states) => const Size.fromHeight(256))
        ),
        menuChildren: 
          _menuList
            .map((i) => MenuItemButton(
              child: SizedBox(
                width: widget.rowWidth / 2 - _offset,
                child: Expanded(child: Text(i)),
              )
            ))
            .toList(),
        builder:(context, controller, child) => Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
          child: TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              if (controller.isOpen) {
                controller.close();
              } else {
                controller.open();
              }
            },
            child: const Text("Add")
          )
        )
      )
    )
  ],
),
```

[menu scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3Fux.gif)

I have attempted to wrap the MenuAnchor in a Scrollbar widget, though this had no effect. I also attempted to assign menuChildren to an array of widgets containing a ListView within a Scrollbar, though this resulted in the application page freezing when the Add button was pressed. The code for this was as follows:

```
menuChildren: <Widget>[
  Scrollbar(
    child: ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (context, index) =>  MenuItemButton(
        child: SizedBox(
          width: widget.rowWidth / 2 - _offset,
          child: Expanded(child: Text(_menuList[index])),
        )
      ),
    )
  )
]
```

How can I add a Scrollbar to the menu list?

Comment: Give list view fixed size and check if it works.

Comment: Thank you for the tip! This works if I wrap the ListView with a SizedBox that has a defined height, however it forces the menu to always be exactly this height, which leaves some blank spaces in the menu. Is there a way for me to make this work without forcing the menu to have a static size? I've tried using a Container and ConstrainedBox with a maxHeight, though this results in the same freezing behavior as before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by using a SingleChildScrollView instead of a ListView, constraining its child's width with a SizedBox, and wrapping it in a LimitedBox so that the height was flexible but the scrollbar still had the height information it needed to render:

```
menuChildren: <Widget>[
  RawScrollbar(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
    child: LimitedBox(
      maxHeight: 256,
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: SizedBox(
          width: widget.rowWidth / 2,
          child: Column(
            children: _menuList
              .map((e) => MenuItemButton(child: Text(e)))
              .toList(),
          ),
        )
      ),
    ),
  ),
]
```

Additionally, this Flutter article about constraints is a fantastic resource: https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/layout/constraints